# Checking to see if two positions are equal

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, sprite, bounding-box

Right now I have a NSMutableArray that holds 3 sprite objects. I need to be able to see if another sprite not in the Array shares the same position as any of the sprites in the array.
I tried doing this:

```
CCSprite *sect;
if (i > maxHealth) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        sect = [tail objectAtIndex:j];
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(sect.boundingBox, playerPos)) {
        NSLog(@"On top");
        return;
    }
```

But it does't work. I think it's trying to see if it intersects all of them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` is outside the `for` loop.  It is only going to test one object; the last one accessed in the loop.